# Azure Stream Analytics outputs an int64 as an int32

Tags: azure, casting, azure-table-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have a Stream Analytics job that converts a timestamp into a number of milliseconds since Epoch.

To do this, I use a JavaScript function that returns a `bigint`, using the following code:

```js
new Date(date).getTime()
```

When I test this job in the Azure portal, I get the correct result, e.g.:
`2018-08-29T13:01:54.0000000Z` becomes `1535547714000`:

[image]

But when I run the job and it starts storing its output in an Azure table, `1535547714000` becomes `-2050577968`.

I noticed that if I cast the `bigint` `1535547714000` into an `int`, I get `-2050577968`. So I checked the type of the column and, strangely, it's `Int64`:

[image]

**TL;DR:**
The job outputs a `bigint`, the column type is <del>`bigint`</del> `Int64` but somehow, somewhere in between, the value seems to be cast into an `int`.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure the JS function would return a bigint since JS only has double-precision floats?

Comment: Well, the output type of the function is `bigint` and the test outputs the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodolphe. If you want to transfer data into Azure Table Storage, you have to follow the rules of it.

Based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types), Azure Table Storage only supports `int32` and `int64` type, no bigint type. So, actually there is no mysterious mechanism to convert your data type, just when the `bigint` data into the table, it is converted to the corresponding `Int64` type.However, it supposed to be `1535547714000`,no way to be converted to int.You could commit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure to post this issue.

As a workaround, you could try to get the data and convert it into Int64 in Azure Table Storage Azure Trigger Function. Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: OK but `bigint` and `Int64` are both 64-bit integers. So, like you said, there shouldn't be any conversion to 32-bit integer. Anyway, I realised that I don't really need the millisecond precision, so I updated my code and it now works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Rodolphe sure. if you don't mind, you could adopt the answer for others' reference,thank you!